# Xamarin Forms - Android - FormsAppCompatActivity - prevent navigate back

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to catch navigating back and depending on some conditions, I need to cancel it.

Note that overriding `OnBackPressed` as suggested in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767357/prevent-closing-by-back-button-in-xamarin-forms-on-android) doesn't work (anymore!?):

```
   public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            base.OnBackPressed();  // not called
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you describe what exactly you are trying to achieve in details, any use case.

Comment: @AkshayKulkarni it's simple, I want to prevent navigating back from the page. This is easy on native, with activities or fragments

Comment: Is this the forms app? And do you want to handle the back button pressed from main page native?

Comment: I just tested this with a new project and overriding `OnBackPressed()` worked. Can you confirm that you are using the latest version of Forms (2.3.2.127)? If you are still having trouble, please attach a minimal reproduction project.

Comment: @jimmgarr don't use device back button. Use the arrow button on the page